# Table angular material does not show any data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i'm making a table component, for this i'm using the table that comes from angular material the dynamic columns are displayed correctly but no data is displayed i can't find the error, i don't have any errors in my console either.

I'd like to point out that I've tried setting my **data** variable directly and it works, but the filter no longer works, so I'm stuck.

thanks.

**table.ts**

```
    export class TemplateTableComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() public columns!: any[];
      @Input() public data!: Beers[];

      public displayedColumns: string[] = [];
      public dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<Beers>;

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Beers>(this.data);
      }

      applyFilter(event: Event) {
        const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
      }
    }
```

**table.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" #input>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
<!-- Column -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns" matColumnDef="{{col.columnDef}}">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ col.header }}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ col.cell(row) }}</td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

<!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
<tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
    <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your data is coming asynchroneously, is not here yet on init and so dataSource is still empty after init.

Implement the dataSource with an input setter, instead of in onInit, and there should be no async issue https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

```
 @Input()
  set data(beers: Beers[]) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Beers>(beers);
  }
```

Note that this replaces your data @Input. You can add the getter if needed.

You can do the same thing implementing onChanges but it is heavier https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges